# When/where to refresh access token in Windows 10 app with azure backend

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, uwp, refresh-token

I'm learning to build Windows 10 apps with an azure backend. I'm using Micosoft Account as my authentication provider. I've learned how to cache access tokens but I'm a little hung up on refresh tokens.

As I understand it, the access token is short lived, and the longer expiring refresh token allows me to get a new access token. I've been trying to follow along with Adrian Hall's book here: https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/realworld/#refresh-tokens

My problem is that I don't quite understand when/where to call or how to use "client.RefreshUserAsync();" and the book isn't really clear.

When should I call refresh?? I guess the problem is that the token might expire in the middle of the user using the app, forcing the user to login again right? So do I call refresh every time my user does anything? I'm confused.

Right now, my app just has a single AuthenticateAsync method on my mainpage that executes when a user clicks a login button. It looks for a cached token, if there is one it checks expiration and re-authenticates if expired.

```
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> AuthenticateAsync()
    {
        string message;
        bool success = false;

        var provider = MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount;

        // Use the PasswordVault to securely store and access credentials
        PasswordVault vault = new PasswordVault();
        PasswordCredential credential = null;

        try
        {
            //try to get an existing credential from the vault.
            credential = vault.FindAllByResource(provider.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //When there is no matching resource an error occurs, which we ignore.
        }

        if (credential != null)
        {

            // Create a user from the stored credentials.
            user = new MobileServiceUser(credential.UserName);
            credential.RetrievePassword();
            user.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken = credential.Password;

            // Set the user from the stored credentials.
            App.MobileService.CurrentUser = user;


            success = true;
            message = string.Format("Cached credentials for user - {0}", user.UserId);

            // Consider adding a check to determine if the token is 
            // expired, as shown in this post: http://aka.ms/jww5vp

            //check expiration
            if (App.MobileService.IsTokenExpired())
            {
                //remove the expired credentials
                vault.Remove(credential);

                try
                {
                    // Login with the identity provider
                    user = await App.MobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount);

                    // Create and store the user credentials.
                    credential = new PasswordCredential(provider.ToString(),
                        user.UserId, user.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken);

                    vault.Add(credential);

                    message = string.Format("Expired credentials caused re-authentication. You are now signed in - {0}", user.UserId);
                    success = true;
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException)
                {
                    message = "You must log in. Login required.";
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                // Login with the identity provider
                user = await App.MobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount);

                // Create and store the user credentials.
                credential = new PasswordCredential(provider.ToString(),
                    user.UserId, user.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken);
                vault.Add(credential);

                message = string.Format("You are now signed in - {0}", user.UserId);
                success = true;
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                message = "You must log in. Login required.";
            }
        }

        var dialog = new MessageDialog(message);
        dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("OK"));
        await dialog.ShowAsync();

        return success;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess the problem is that the token might expire in the middle of the user using the app, forcing the user to login again right?

Based on your description, you use Azure mobile app as your UWP backend. To access mobile app we need to use access token. and as you know that, access token will be expired. In order to get a new access token, we need to use refresh token. For how to get access token by refresh token, please refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#refreshing-the-access-tokens). Below is detailed http request info:

```
// Line breaks for legibility only

POST /{tenant}/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&refresh_token=OAAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLWQJVzCTE9UkP3pSx1aXxUjq...
&grant_type=refresh_token
&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F
&client_secret=JqQX2PNo9bpM0uEihUPzyrh    // NOTE: Only required for web apps
```

From above http request, we only provide client_id, refresh_token, grant_type, resource, client_secret(web app only). So we need not to let user login again.

> When should I call refresh??

If the access token is expired, it will get error when we access mobile app. At this moment we can try to get a new access token by refresh token in the catch{} logic.

Comment: So if I'm understanding you correctly, everywhere that I'm making a call to the backend, I should catch the error, refresh the user, and attempt  the call again.

Comment: you can simply call the refresh API in the Azure Mobile Apps SDK to refresh the token when you get auth error. Please try to use the new access token to see if it works.